# Amazon S3 server's bucket url fire XMLhttp request can not load error for PDF.js library

Tags: backbone.js, nginx, amazon-s3, requirejs, pdf.js

JS library in backbone, require.js web application to render PDF page. The PDF page exist on Amazon S3 server, for fetching that I am calling REST API which will return that https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/asjkasjkasj.pdf. But I am getting XMLhttp request can not load

```js
this.$el.find(".pdf").attr("src", "/static/lib/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=/api/pdf/url/asjkasjkasj");

//the final url will be
// http://localhot/static/lib/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=http://localhost/api/pdf/url/asjkasjkasj
//and it will return

//http://localhot/static/lib/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=https://s3.amazon.com/bucket/asjkasjkasj.pdf
```

```html
<iframe id="pdf" width="100%" scrolling="no" tabindex="0" vspace="0" class="" allowtransparency="true" aria-hidden="true" frameborder="0" hspace="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>
```

No `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is present on requested source.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [PDF.js documentation](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#faq-xhr), you can load a PDF from another server by:

- Enable CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing)

  To enable CORS in AWS S3, you can add this in **Edit CORS Configuration** inside bucket **Permission Properties**:

  ```xml
  <CORSConfiguration>
      <CORSRule>
          <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
          <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
          <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
      </CORSRule>
  </CORSConfiguration>
  ```

  Test your CORS using:

  ```
  curl -H "Origin: http://stackoverflow.com" -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: GET" -H "Access-Control-Request-Headers: X-Requested-With" -I https://s3.amazon.com/bucket/asjkasjkasj.pdf
  ```

  Make sure you see `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`. And then test using your PDF.js.
- Create a proxy inside your server to download the PDF file from S3